# Program to count the frequency of numbers in a txt file and o/p the result in another txt file?

Tags: java, file-io, count

I'm writing a program to count the number of times the number occurs in a twxt file. The input to the text is given at the run time. The input is stored in the text file, now i have to count the frequency and output the result in another text file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentPoll
{

private Scanner x;
int[] frequency = new int[5];
int count =0;
 public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.printf("No File found");
    }
    }
  public void readFile(){
    while(x.hasNext()){
       int a= x.nextInt(); 
           if(a==1){
               frequency[0]=0;
            ++frequency[0];
            break;
        }
       else if (a== 2){
                       frequency[1]=0;
                ++frequency[1];
                break;
       }
       else if( a==3){
                frequency[2]=0;
                ++frequency[2];
                break;
       }
       else if (a==4){
                frequency[3]=0;
                ++frequency[3];
                break;
       }
       else if (a== 5){
           frequency[4]=0;
               ++frequency [4];
               break;

       }

       }     


          System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","Rating","Frequency");
          System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","1",++frequency[0]); 
          System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","2",++frequency[1]); 
          System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","3",++frequency[2]); 
          System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","4",++frequency[3]); 
          System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","5",++frequency[4]); 



    }
}


public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
```

I should get the output as:

```
Rating  Frequency
1         1
2         2
3         1
4         1
5         1
```

But the frequency count is incorrect. I don't know what is the error I'm making here.

I also don't know how to write this output to another file. What do I need to change?

Comment: What does the input file look like? What output are you actually getting?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the initialization of your arrays out of the  `nextInt()` part of the loop. Otherwise, every time you find a new number, you reset the count to zero.

Change:

```
public void readFile(){
    while(x.hasNext()){
       int a= x.nextInt(); 
           if(a==1){
               frequency[0]=0;
            ++frequency[0];
            break;
        }
```

to:

```
public void readFile(){
    while(x.hasNext()){
               frequency[0]=0;
               frequency[1]=0;
               // ... etc etc
       int a= x.nextInt(); 
           if(a==1){
            ++frequency[0];
            break;
        }
```

and remove the rest of the `frequency[x]=0` from in the loop.

Also, the ++frequency[x] calls in the print statements shouldn't be there.  You don't want to increment every time you print the list.  It would also make more sense to loop through the arrays, rather than have a printf for each one.

Comment: I did change it, but the o/p is showing the count only for the 1st number entered, since " int a = x. NextInt()  is initialized, do I need to put any for loop here? But the while loop should check the condition?

Comment: for the input in file 1,2,3,4,5,1, iam getting the o/p as           > rating   frequency                                                            1     1                                                                    2 0                                                                    3  0                                                                       4 0                                                                     5      0

Comment: @HarithaDasari Can you show the new code (just the readFile() method) in an edit to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the count everytime with `frequency[xxx]=0;`. Simply remove all those statements as the array elements will automatically be initialised with a default value, which is 0 for `int`.

Comment: i removed those, but the loop is not running, since it is just taking one value that is given first and for the rest the count is coming as 0. So, how to move to the next variabble in the text file. what methods do i need to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
frequency[0]=0;
++frequency[0];
```

you reset frequency every time number matches, and you also increments frequency when printing results.

Replace `int[] frequency = new int[5]` with 
`int[] frequency = [0,0,0,0,0]` and 
`System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","1",++frequency[0]);` with
`System.out.printf("%s%10s\n","1",frequency[0]);`

Comment: `int[] frequency = [0,0,0,0,0]` does not compile (`int[] frequency = {0,0,0,0,0]}` does) and is unnecessary: arrays are always initialised in Java.